# Can I block upvotes on my own answer?

Tags: feature-request, reputation, upvotes

A few days ago I answered a question about an easy issue about C/C++.
In general, several answers were upvoted by a lot of people.
I think my answer is right and deserves 1 or 2 upvotes, but no more.
However I have 21 upvotes up to know.

[If-else question in C/C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24373076/is-else-if-a-single-keyword/24373094?noredirect=1#comment37692317_24373094)

I don't want to delete my answer, because I think it is a good one.
But I don't want to have a lot of upvotes by what I consider an almost silly answer.

I have worked a lot in answering other very difficult questions about C, and I have obtained just a few upvotes for them.
I think that my reputation was growing according to that effort in a fair pace.

But, on the other hand, now I gained 210 reputation points very easily by answering a trivial thing about if-else statements in C/C++.

This behaviour in the website pervert the right way in that reputation works.
Any lucky guy could obtain a bunch of reputation without great effort, with the final result that silly guys become moderators with high privileges.

If a question is easy to answer, the moderators would have to be able to indicate that this is the case, and automatically an anti-enthusiastic mechanism be triggered, in such a manner that a maximum of upvotes be accepted, or well, giving a less value to the upvotes for that particular question.

Comment: I say leave it as-is. Take it as recompense for a future answer where you do a lot of research, offer an elegant solution, and get almost no upvotes.

Comment: Hard questions are the ones almost nobody understands to begin with, but trivial ones attract huge roving mobs of new programmers. The population of voters who understand easy questions is large, and the population that understands the hard ones is small. The voting populations follows this. If you don't want highly upvoted easy answers, then don't answer easy questions. Welcome to dealing with The Public.

Comment: An answer's score is primarily a measure of the number of people who found it helpful. Quality is secondary to the breadth of the audience. Effort only matters to the extent that it improves quality. (i.e. only results matter). While you might feel that you deserve more reputation points for investing a lot of effort into answering a hard question than it tossing out a quick answer to an easy one, that's not the way the system works (both in design and in practice).

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can make your answer a *Community Wiki* post.

Community Wiki posts do not earn you any reputation, and are easier to edit (lower rep requirement) by other users.

There is a checkbox below the post editor; check it and it'll be a CW post on saving:

> [image: Community wiki checkbox location]

Also see

- [What are "Community Wiki" posts?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11740/what-are-community-wiki-posts)

Comment: Done. However, I am not sure if my answer qualifies for a Community-wiki answer. It is just an answer. A more complete and best answer was another one.

Comment: If you don't think your answer is good enough then you can always delete it and post it as a comment instead.

Comment: @JeroenVannevel: No. I think my answer is good enough. But there are better answers. That's all. I don't think my answer have to be deleted. But it has not to be excesivelly upvoted, also. It is just an answer that it has to be right there, but with less votes that actually have.

Comment: "A more complete and best answer was another one" -- if you believe this is important, consider editing your answer to add a link referring to a better one, preferably along with explanation of why you think it's better